# How to get the pointer value from a vector of pointers of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a  vector<Octree*> children variable where each point in the octree is an RGB value (made of 3 components).When I do

```
int G1= children[i]->point->G;
```

I get the address as an int not the value . How can I de-reference the pointer in this case?

this is the function where I use it:

vector Octree::find(int R,int G, int B)
{

```
  vector<RGBvalues> result;

    int midR = (topLeftFront->R
                + bottomRightBack->R)
               / 2;
    int midG = (topLeftFront->G
                + bottomRightBack->G)
               / 2;
    int midB = (topLeftFront->B
                + bottomRightBack->B)
               / 2;

    int pos = -1;

    // Deciding the position
    // where to move
    if (R <= midR) {
        if (G <= midG) {
            if (B <= midB)
                pos = TopLeftFront;
            else
                pos = TopLeftBottom;
        }
        else {
            if (B <= midB)
                pos = BottomLeftFront;
            else
                pos = BottomLeftBack;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (G <= midG) {
            if (B <= midB)
                pos = TopRightFront;
            else
                pos = TopRightBottom;
        }
        else {
            if (B <= midB)
                pos = BottomRightFront;
            else
                pos = BottomRightBack;
        }
    }

    // If an internal node is encountered
    if (children[pos]->point == nullptr) {
        return children[pos]->find(R,G,B);
    }

    // If an empty node is encountered
    else if (children[pos]->point->R == -1) {
        return vector<RGBvalues>();
    }

    else {

        // If node is found with
        // the given value
        if (R == children[pos]->point->R
            && G == children[pos]->point->G
            && B == children[pos]->point->B)

          { for(int i= 0;i<8;i++ )

             { int R1 =children[pos]->point->R;
             int G1= children[i]->point->G;
             int B1= children[i]->point->B;
             RGBvalues rez;
             rez.R= R1;
             rez.G= G1;
             rez.B= B1;
             result.push_back(rez);
            }


            return result ;

          }
    return vector<RGBvalues>();
    }
}
```

When I tried debugging, in the last if condition I get the correct R value when writing if (R == children[pos]->point->R) but not when I do  children[i]->point->R

THIS IS THE Octree class:

```
#define TopLeftFront 0
#define TopRightFront 1
#define BottomRightFront 2
#define BottomLeftFront 3
#define TopLeftBottom 4
#define TopRightBottom 5
#define BottomRightBack 6
#define BottomLeftBack 7
    class Octree{
    
          RGBvalues* point;
          RGBvalues *topLeftFront, *bottomRightBack;
         vector<Octree*> children;
    
     public:
    
         Octree();
        Octree(int x, int y, int z);
        Octree(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2);
    
        void insert(int x, int y , int z);
        vector<RGBvalues> find(int x, int y, int z);
           bool findValue(int x, int y, int z);
    
    };
```

AND THE RGBvalues struct:

```
struct RGBvalues{
  int R;
  int G;
  int B;

  RGBvalues()
          : R(-1), G(-1), B(-1)
      {
      }

   RGBvalues(int a, int b, int c)
          : R(a), G(b), B(c)
      {
      }
};
```

HERE IS THE REST OF THE CODE that creates and inserts in an octree, if you find it helpful:

```
       Octree::Octree()
    {
        // To declare empty node
        point = new RGBvalues();
    }

    // Constructor with three arguments
   Octree:: Octree(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        // To declare point node
        point = new RGBvalues(x, y, z);
    }

    // Constructor with six arguments
    Octree::Octree(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2)
    {

        point = nullptr;
        topLeftFront
            = new RGBvalues(x1, y1, z1);
        bottomRightBack
            = new RGBvalues(x2, y2, z2);

        // Assigning null to the children
        children.assign(8, nullptr);
        for (int i = TopLeftFront;
             i <= BottomLeftBack;
             ++i)
            children[i] = new Octree();
    }

    // Function to insert a point in the octree
    void Octree::insert(int R, int G, int B)
    {

         if (findValue(R,G,B)) {

                   return;
               }


        // Binary search to insert the point
        int midR = (topLeftFront->R
                    + bottomRightBack->R)
                   / 2;
        int midG = (topLeftFront->G
                    + bottomRightBack->G)
                   / 2;
        int midB = (topLeftFront->B
                    + bottomRightBack->B)
                   / 2;

        int pos = -1;

        // Checking the octant of
        // the point
        if (R <= midR) {
            if (G <= midG) {
                if (B <= midB)
                    pos = TopLeftFront;
                else
                    pos = TopLeftBottom;
            }
            else {
                if (B <= midB)
                    pos = BottomLeftFront;
                else
                    pos = BottomLeftBack;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (G <= midG) {
                if (B <= midB)
                    pos = TopRightFront;
                else
                    pos = TopRightBottom;
            }
            else {
                if (B <= midB)
                    pos = BottomRightFront;
                else
                    pos = BottomRightBack;
            }
        }

        // If an internal node is encountered
        if (children[pos]->point == nullptr) {
            children[pos]->insert(R,G,B);
            return;
        }

        // If an empty node is encountered
        else if (children[pos]->point->R == -1) {
            delete children[pos];
            children[pos] = new Octree(R, G, B);
            return;
        }
        else {
            int R_ = children[pos]->point->R,
                G_ = children[pos]->point->G,
                B_ = children[pos]->point->B;
            delete children[pos];
            children[pos] = nullptr;
            if (pos == TopLeftFront) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(topLeftFront->R,
                                           topLeftFront->G,
                                           topLeftFront->B,
                                           midR,
                                           midG,
                                           midB);
            }

            else if (pos == TopRightFront) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(midR + 1,
                                           topLeftFront->G,
                                           topLeftFront->B,
                                           bottomRightBack->R,
                                           midG,
                                           midB);
            }
            else if (pos == BottomRightFront) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(midR + 1,
                                           midG + 1,
                                           topLeftFront->B,
                                           bottomRightBack->R,
                                           bottomRightBack->G,
                                           midB);
            }
            else if (pos == BottomLeftFront) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(topLeftFront->R,
                                           midG + 1,
                                           topLeftFront->B,
                                           midR,
                                           bottomRightBack->G,
                                           midB);
            }
            else if (pos == TopLeftBottom) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(topLeftFront->R,
                                           topLeftFront->G,
                                           midB + 1,
                                           midR,
                                           midG,
                                           bottomRightBack->B);
            }
            else if (pos == TopRightBottom) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(midR + 1,
                                           topLeftFront->G,
                                           midB + 1,
                                           bottomRightBack->R,
                                           midG,
                                           bottomRightBack->B);
            }
            else if (pos == BottomRightBack) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(midR + 1,
                                           midG + 1,
                                           midB + 1,
                                           bottomRightBack->R,
                                           bottomRightBack->G,
                                           bottomRightBack->B);
            }
            else if (pos == BottomLeftBack) {
                children[pos] = new Octree(topLeftFront->R,
                                           midG + 1,
                                           midB + 1,
                                           midR,
                                           bottomRightBack->G,
                                           bottomRightBack->B);
            }

            children[pos]->insert(R_,G_, B_);
            children[pos]->insert(R,G,B);
        }
    }
```

In the find() function I want an RGBvalues vector of the brothers of the node I was looking for ( including him) ,if you have other suggestions on how to do that, it is very welcomed.
Everything works fine except the segmentation fault I get at that if().
I think a problem is that in the children vector there can be null pointers as well so I can't push-back() that.

Comment: It would help to see the class definition of `Octree` and any types it uses.

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: `int R1 =children[pos]->point->R;` uses `pos`, but the next two lines use `i`. That looks suspicious.

Comment: I now added as many details as I could, hope it helps

Comment: but pos is an integer between 0 and 7 so I think it shouldn't matter?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mre]. For starters, a definition of `RGBvalues` must be included because the code mentions it.

Comment: I did, if you could please reopen the question